# how to test core data model used in a framework in swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data

I'm writing a swift framework and I'm using a template from 'pod lib create' command. in my development pods, I've created a core data model file and I'm using core data in my framework. now I want to write unit tests for it. this is my unit test class code:

```swift
import XCTest
import CoreData
@testable import MyFramework

class MyClassTests: XCTestCase {

    var testPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer?

    override func setUp() {
        let persistentStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        persistentStoreDescription.type = NSInMemoryStoreType

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyCoreDataModelFileName")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [persistentStoreDescription]
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        self.testPersistentContainer = container
    }

    override func tearDown() {

    }

    func testSomething() {
        // the persistent container I'm trying to use is nil
        XCTAssertNotNil(self.testPersistentContainer)
    }
}
```

I know what is the problem, the problem is that the test target can't find my core data model file, and when I create a file with a proper name in my example app target, the above test passes. but

**Question**

What is the correct way of testing the core data model of a framework?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you want to test your model? If your plan is to create a model, save it, and test that it is correctly persisted, your are actually testing the CoreData framework itself, which is probably a bad idea, Apple already took care of that for you.

Comment: I don't want to test core data functionality, I want to test my functions, for example if I user myClass.add(something), I want to test that it saves something in core that or not. and so on ...

Comment: Okey, I didn't use CoreData for a while, but have you checked that your model file is linked to your test target (the right panel in Xcode)?

Comment: it's not, and my main problem is that I don't know how to link it in cocoa pod lib template, because when I click on model file, Xcode don't shows main app or test target, instead it shows frameworks and pods targets.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "when I create a file with a proper name in my example app target"? I'm also interested in this issue, but even just a workaround will do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the Core Data model from the framework bundle?

```
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: nil)
```

Then you won't need to add it to your test target